# Error persist new data using existing and non-existing data in database jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `Book` table and `Author` table. Their relationship is `many-to-many`.

**My Objective**

I want to able to persist new book. If the author of the books is already exist in `Author` table, I dont want to persist same author in `Author` table. If the author is doesn't exist in `Author` table, the author data will persisted in `Author` table. Here is how I declare the entity and the serviceImplementation to save the data:

**Book**

```
@Entity(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false)
    private String year;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
      name = "book_author",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Author> author;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
    private BookCategory category;
}
```

**Author**

```
@Entity(name = "author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Book> book;
}
```

**BookServiceImpl**

```
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    @Override
    public BookDto save(BookDto bookDto) throws Exception {
        try {
            Book book = new Book();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(bookDto, book, "author", "category");
            BookCategory bookCategory = bookCategoryDao.findByCategory(bookDto.getCategory());

            Set<Author> dataAuthor = new HashSet<Author>();
            Set<AuthorDto> dataAuthorDto = new HashSet<AuthorDto>();
            bookDto.getAuthor().iterator().forEachRemaining(dataAuthorDto::add);

            for (AuthorDto authorDto : dataAuthorDto) {
                Author author = new Author();
                Author author_ = authorDao.findByName(authorDto.getName());
                if (null == author_) {
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(authorDto, author);
                } else {
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(author_, author);
                }

                dataAuthor.add(author);
            }

            book.setAuthor(dataAuthor);
            book.setCategory(bookCategory);
            bookDao.save(book);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Here is the sample json input when I make the request:

```
{
    "title": "book1",
    "year": "2013",
    "author": [
        {
            "name": "angel",
            "address": "NY"
        }, {
            "name": "john",
            "address": "LA"
        }
    ],
    "category": "science"
}
```

Above code is works if all the author are either exist in `Author` table or not exist at all in `Author` table. If one of them exist and the other is not exist, it will throw error based on `CascadeType` that I used in defining the entity.

**Error**

Using use case "one author exist in Author table and the other is not exist in Author table", here are the error based on the `CascadeType`:

1. If I use `CascadeType.all` => `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist`, which because persisting the author is only success if they have no id, because id of author is annotated with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.
2. If I remove `CascadeType` or use `CascadeType.MERGE` => `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`, which because I have a collection that has one or more items which are not present in the database (`Author` table).

So, what is the right way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try it like this:

```
for (AuthorDto authorDto : dataAuthorDto) {
    Author author = authorDao.findByName(authorDto.getName());
    if (null == author) {
        author = new Author();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(authorDto, author);
    }
    dataAuthor.add(author);
}
```

This way if you find an author in the database, you reference the existing author with your book instead of creating a new one. This way you don't end up with two identical authors in the persistence context (the one you found with the findByName, and the one you created and referenced with your book). I didn't test this solution, please let me know in the comments if it doesn't work.

Comment: perfect. Thanks! you saved my night! Note, still using cascadetype.all with your answer